# get back to initramfs on shutdown

Tags: chroot, initramfs

I have got my own initramfs running its own init script. After doing some things, it finally calls switch_root and executes the init script of the system, which is mounted in /mnt.
Now I want to **get back to the initramfs' init script** when Linux shuts down (so the init script from linux quits)

But because im calling `exec switch_root /mnt /blah/init`, the script terminates when Linux shuts down. But I want to do some things after that in my initramfs, which is not possible that way.

What I can do is `chroot /mnt` instead of `switch_root ...`, so when Linux shuts down, im back inside the init script. But this has the nasty side effect that some applications such as netctl will refuse to work, because they are called from inside a chrooted system.

So **what I need** is a way to `switch_root` into the system and finally get back to the initramfs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `pivot_root` instead of `switch_root` (which deletes everything!).

If your init system won't complain about not being `pid 1`, you might be done there.

The alternative solution is to make your init system be nice enough to `pivot_root` itself into a ... what do you call it? shutdownramfs? That has nothing to do with initramfs but is the same principle that would let you perform a shutdown action or another.

I don't think there is a standard solution since it should rarely be necessary to do anything on shutdown.

Comment: Thanks, thats okay for my script (pid != 1), but what do you mean with pivot_root deletes everything?

Comment: `switch_root` deletes all files in `/` before switching. As for the shutdown initramfs it seems `dracut` does it https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/boot/dracut/dracut.html#_dracut_on_shutdown

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using `dracut`.

1. Have a backup in case anything going wrong such as an unbootable system.
2. Switch to `dracut` (instead of `initramfs-tools`).

   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install --no-install-recommends dracut
3. A custom written [`dracut` module](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dracut-core/dracut.modules.7.en.html) will be required.
4. A `dracut` `cleanup` hooks needs to run `dracut` function `need_shutdown`.

This results in `dracut` creating file `/run/initramfs/.need_shutdown`.

At shutdown time `/lib/systemd/system/dracut-shutdown.service` to run `/usr/lib/dracut/dracut-initramfs-restore`, which will restore the initramfs and pivot into it.

5. A `dracut` `shutdown` hooks will be required. If implemented, it will be executed very late at the shutdown process inside initramfs.

`cold-boot-attack-defense` is a `dracut` example module which does all of that.

References:

- https://github.com/Kicksecure/security-misc#cold-boot-attack-defense
- https://www.kicksecure.com/wiki/Dev/RAM_Wipe
- [`/usr/lib/dracut/modules.d/40cold-boot-attack-defense`](https://github.com/Kicksecure/security-misc/tree/master/usr/lib/dracut/modules.d/40cold-boot-attack-defense)

Full disclosure:

`cold-boot-attack-defense` has been developed by me.

How about doing this using `initramfs-tools`?

You'd have to implement a similar mechanism yourself for `initramfs-tools`. [Tails did that.](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/memory_erasure/). Emulating that might be quite a bit harder than even doing what was described above for `dracut`. Or maybe the solution posted in [`initramfs-tools` Debian feature request: Support restoring initrd on shutdown and pivoting into it](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=778849)
 provides an easier path while using `initramfs-tools`. However, using `dracut` will be easier since this is a `dracut` default feature.