# Back to "initramfs" on Debian by systemd "shutdown to initramfs" feature

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, systemd, initramfs

I need to go back to initramfs during shutdown in order to do a clean unmount of the [loopback devices which host my linux installation](https://github.com/DareDevil73/linux-on-loopback-usb/issues/1).

To achieve that goal I have read a lot of [documentation](https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2017/04/msg00079.html) and [source code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/core/shutdown.c) about the [shutdown to initramfs](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/InitrdInterface/) feature.

Unfortunately [it seems unsupported](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/392178/141129) on Debian.

I believe it maybe quite simple to implement by writing shutdown services like the [dracut ones](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/dracut-shutdown.service.8.html), but to avoid a waste of time I would ask you if yet exists a pre-built solution for that.

Thank you so much,
Antonio

Comment: My answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/708693/49297 explains this and links to an example implementation.

Comment: This question seems to me to be a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215169/get-back-to-initramfs-on-shutdown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of experiments I have stated that hacking initramfs tools would not be a stable solution, so I have chosen to rely directly on Dracut.

The complete solution is hosted on GitHub [at this URL](https://github.com/antonio-petricca/buddy-linux).